How to create book-style paragraphs in org mode for html export
I would like to use org-mode to create book-like page formatting where the paragraphs have no line gap between and the start of the paragraph is indented a tab's width for org-mode export to html.
I've seen some half-dozen supposed work-arounds ... that don't work for exactly this scenario, i.e., org-mode export to html. Maddeningly close, but no cigar. IOW, I need org-mode to think soft instead of hard returns between paragraph blocks, as well as a tab indentation at the start. Now I'm kludging soft returns with \\ at the end of every paragraph text block, which eliminates the blank separating line. Then I start the paragraph block with @@html:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp@@
@@html:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp@@ Blah and blah and blah...and blah.\\

And this does work. But throwing such a kludge at literally every paragraph in a 100k+-word book would be a chore indeed. Or not. I suppose a smart find-replace macro would do too. Any ideas?

This is a CSS matter. Add the following to your Org mode file:
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
...

and create a CSS style file, style1.css, in the same directory as the Org mode file:
p { margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; text-indent: 2em; }

Season to taste.
Note that a "tab's width" does not mean anything to CSS or HTML.
You don't have to worry about soft vs. hard returns: the Org mode HTML exporter formats paragraphs the way you prescribe: just use the standard convention of separating paragraphs (whether they are a single or multiple lines) by an empty line.
Alternatively, you can include the contents of the style file in your Org mode file and avoid a separate CSS file. But that becomes messy for anything more complicated than what you are doing here:
#+HTML_HEAD: <style>p { margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; text-indent: 2em; } </style>
...

